# Where does my Controller finds the data?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, dbcontext

I'm having trouble to understand where my Controller is finding the data. I have a Class/Model

[image]

That "Generates/Creates" a database based(?) on this modell. And I have added som information with some help from the mvc CRUD template.

[image]

Now here I am completeley lost. Where does my controller get (Name = Dave, Age = 45) ? Since I don't have a DB visible and **I don't have a connection string** to my DB in my Web.config file. How does my controller know where to get this data? How does DbContext works?

Comment: Are you sure you have no connection string ? Your dbcontext looks like working

Comment: What do you have in your global.asax ?

Comment: How is your UserDBContext defined? when not calling base constructor, I do believe EF first uses the connection string based on the context name, and after this the database with the name of the context/connection string relative to executing assembly.

Comment: @Adrien It just says this. `public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }`

Comment: @DevilSuichiro It is defined as you can see on the images. And as you can see also, I don't have a DB.

Comment: I think that app always create some connection tu local DB, if no DB connection is specified. Look at your Server explorer to Data connection.

Comment: What do you have beside your web.config ? web.debug.config ?

Comment: @Adrien Yeah and Web.Release.config.If you mean the Web.config at the bottom.

Comment: ok. Do you have a connection string in web.debug.config ? This file overrides the web.config in a debug mode.

Comment: @Adrien No I do not. It's about 95% comments about some "stuff"